# Resize Flex TileList height according to Number of rows

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, components

I have a canvas which display some images in grid view (Like google images search result page) to bring such Output I used TileList with each tile width/height  are hard coded to (15/125).height and width of the TileList component is 100% , everything works perfect on all resolution Am able to see increase/decrease in row/column count as per the screen resolution.

I want to put the TileList component to HBox with some Wid/Heig and i want the scroll for HBox rather than to the TileList.Since the TileList is extension of List component so all the viewable items on the TileList are swapped according to how much we are scrolling , now i have a hard time in increasing the height of the TileList component according to the content so that I can scroll my parent container.

Any help is appreciated,Thanks!

Comment: If you make the list as big as all the content then you lose the recycling of item renderers that the list classes offer you.  In doing so you're basically reducing the list to being a complex version of a repeater, you might as well just use a repeater in this case and add the rollover effect if you'd like.

Comment: You are rite by increasing the height of the TileList leads to performance issue , but I want bring a output similar to this page http://wireless.amazon.com/b/684177011/ref=topnav_br_ph?ie=UTF8&class=link